# Sending as Access Report via e-mail, but with other attachments

Tags: ms-access, outlook

I am aware that within Access you can send a report as an e-mail attachment with

```
DoCmd.SendObject
```

However, all the text I have read says you cannot add attachments (other than the report you are adding).  So there is another set of web articles which go on to describe how to use vba to send an outlook e-mail message.

The report is a letter, and the other attachments I need to add are pdf's with maps in them, selecting which pdf depends on some other criteria.

I am thinking about enhancing the report to have the other attachments in the report, but I think that could be more trouble, so my ideal would be to avoid that if I can.  The question is can I?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the report as a PDF using this code:

[Save Report as PDF File](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=789)

Then use the Outlook VBA code you have to send the report along with the other files you need to send.

If you need specific help writing the code, please update your question with more details such as file location, Office version, what code you were planning to use, etc.

Comment: I am half way through trying something similar but different.  Basically I create a report in snapshot file format and then convert the snapshot file to PDF using some DLL's found on Stephen Leban's site www.lebans.com - I'll report further when its working

Comment: @akc42 OK, if you figure it out please post it as an answer and accept it so others can see your issue was resolved.